# Forcing redirect for logged in users

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a website for a client https://www.virtualflooringco.com.au and it is a website that is behind password due to franchise conditions, but the page located at /login can be accessed by already logged in users.

I want to force visitors that go to the login page and that are already logged in to be redirected to /home. Currently I have a button on the login page that if they are already logged in, to click and it'll take them to that /home link, but I'm looking for a more professional solution.

I have looked through stackoverflow and can't seem to find anything that related to what I'm trying to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For Wordpress, if you want to redirect logged in users you may simply install one of the redirect plugins. (e.g. LoginWP [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/peters-login-redirect/)) and then you can set the URL(s) for redirection according to the user role

Comment: I'm not worried about redirecting as they login, I have that setup already. It's simply if they close the website and go to reopen it again and the customers browser still has them logged in, it will automatically forward them to mydomain.com/home/

Comment: If they close the website and re-open and you want the system to redirect --- you need cookies. (something like "remember my login")

Comment: You need to show the code you have already tried to make users of the site more likely to help.

Answer (score 1):

Use an authentication to your login function. When the user submits their user details, the PHP code will compare the submitted data to your database.

If match found, then it sets the users logged-in session. In this authentication code, it preserves the `user id` in a `PHP session`.

After of authentication, the `PHP $_SESSION` super global variable will contain the `user id`. Example, $_SESSION[“user_id”] is set to manage the logged-in session. It will remain until log out or quit from the browser.

And in logout, unset all the session variables using PHP unset() function.

Comment: Sorry, that went way over my head.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
function redirect_to_home() {
    // Check if we are logedin and we are on login page
    if(!is_admin() && is_page('login') && is_user_logged_in()) {
      //redirect to homepage if we try to access login page.
      wp_redirect(home_url().'/home');
      exit();
    }
  }
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_to_home');
```

Comment: So, www.virtualflooringco.com.au/login is set as the home page

I want that if people view the homepage, they are automatically redirected to www.virtualflooringco.com.au/home

Comment: That code in the functions.php game me the error: 
Unable to communicate back with site to check for fatal errors, so the PHP change was reverted. You will need to upload your PHP file change by some other means, such as by using SFTP.

Comment: The code is tested and works. When i try to access your website i am always redirected to wp-login . I dont understand what you are trying to do. In wp_redirect() point to your desire url to redirect for example wp_redirect(home_url().'/home'));

Comment: Okay so you are using Woocommerce so this change how to redirect. You have to use woocommerce_login_redirect hook since you are using woo login form. For your registration form use woocommerce_registration_redirect  if you want redirection.

Comment: I'm basically wanting to force logged in users that when they land on /login/ it forwards them to /home/ so I can delete the button that says "if already logged in, please click here"

Comment: I have updated the code to redirect to url/home . Tested and works.